# Sequencing Signature in Docusign by using API

Tags: docusignapi

How the same contract to two different people (Husband and Wife) can be sent at the same time but want them to sign it in a sequence. Firstly it should be signed with the first person and then that signed copy will be sent to another person to sign. How it can be achieved with the help of API to do it in a sequence. Any help on this matter is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by using the ["Signing Order"](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-signing-order) feature

You can use this API datapoint as seen in the [official documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#signers-recipient)

```
routingOrder    Yes     String  This element specifies the routing order of the recipient in the envelope.
```